# If body class is the same as another class, add a new class

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to match the body class (auto generated by Wordpress) to an li class (also auto generated). If they match then I need to add a new class to the li.

E.g

If `body` is `class="postid-621"` and an `li` on the page is `class="postid-621"` then I need to enter a new class into the `li` called `current-product`.

Bear in mind that the id is auto generated so I can't just hard code that in.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please show us your code so we can help you.

Comment: have your tried to use jQuery hasClass() ?

Comment: which li to target? i mean the parent of the li or better to post the markup piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one serious problem, in Wordpress the body usually has a lot of classes, the standard theme has something like :

```
 <body class="single single-post postid-621 single-format-standard masthead-fixed singular">
```

so you have to actually get the `postid` class, and compare the numbers, as that's probably what you want.

```
$('#test').attr('class').split(/\s+/).filter(function(k) {
    if ( $.trim(k).indexOf('postid') === 0 ) {
        $('li.' + $.trim(k)).addClass('new_class_to_add');
    }
});
```

Just getting the class attribute and comparing that will fail in Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("body").attr("class") == $("#liId").attr("class")) {
            $("#liId").addClass("newclass");
        }

    });
```

**Edit**

```
if( $("li").hasClass($("body").attr("class")))
{
   $("li").addClass("newclass");
  }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what the `#liID` is?

Comment: @AnoopJosji It just needs to add the new class to the li if it matches the body class (there may be other classes in both elements).

Answer (score 0):

I assume the class names you posted is just an example, and you want to assign the class to any li which is having the same class as the body

```
jQuery(function($){
    var clazz = $('body').attr('class');
    if(clazz){
        $('li.' + clazz).addClass('current-product')
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes they are just examples and are generated dynamically. Does it matter that there's other classes in the body and li's?

Comment: Yes, that would affect things. We have to know which class to look at.